# Safely move (and extend) Ubuntu Partition

Tags: 14.04, boot, dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

So I know this question has probably been asked before but I am having trouble finding an answer specific to my problem and I really dont want to ruin my machine and have to reinstall both operating systems. But basically:

1) Windows 7 was installed

2) I installed Ubuntu with only 30GB of space

3) I am running out of space on Ubuntu so I want to extend the partition

4) I shrank the Windows partition using GParted on a LiveUSB drive

Now I have an unallocated partition that I would like to use to extend Ubuntu. The unallocated partition comes before the Ubuntu partition.

Is it safe to do so?

Note: I know I must use GParted through LiveUSB and all my data is already backed up.

GParted screenshot: [screenshot of partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awf7k.jpg)

Comment: Upload the screenshot in http://imgur.com and [edit](http://askubuntu.com/posts/642931/edit) your question and add the link to the image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In principle (without actually seeing your partition layout) you should be able to simply extend the Ubuntu partition using the unallocated space.  This process ought to be perfectly safe.  However, in real life, nothing is guaranteed.  Why not use disk imaging software (e.g. Macrium Reflect Free Edition for Windows, Clonezilla for Linux) to make a backup of the entire hard disk just in case things go south with GParted?  Otherwise, there is an excellent tutorial on the use of GParted for multiple disk operations at:  http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/gparted.html#mozTocId247821

Comment: I have added a  link to a screenshot of my partitions if it helps at all

Comment: And because it comes after the unallocated space, don't I have to move it first?

Comment: I think that, by default, GParted will move the data in the partition to the left when the partition is resized (see: http://gparted.org/display-doc.php?name=help-manual#gparted-resize-partition)

Comment: Okay, so if I resize (and move) the partition using GParted, since it is contains my boot directory, the boot up will fail and I will need to reinstall grub right?

Comment: Quite likely that you will need to reinstall grub.  Some info. on this is posted at: https://linuxnorth.wordpress.com/2013/01/09/re-installing-grub2/